# how to create elb inside vpc using boto?

Tags: python, boto

```
def create_lb(lb_name):
   'create a new load balancer'

   region = ['ap-southeast-1']
   zones = ['none']
   subnets = ['subnet-0d0b3379']
   ports= [(80, 80, 'http'), (443, 443, 'tcp')]
   lb = lb_conn.create_load_balancer(lb_name, zones, subnets, ports)
   hc = HealthCheck(
            interval=20,
            healthy_threshold=3,
            unhealthy_threshold=5,
            target='HTTP:80/health')
   lb.configure_health_check(hc)
   print lb.dns_name
```

Using above definition I am creating the lb inside a vpc, but it shows:

```
<Code>MalformedInput</Code>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think...we need provide at-least 2 subnets to create loadbalancer .!

Answer (score 0):

The value `none` is not valid for the `zones` parameter.  You have to specify at least one valid availability zone for the region in which you have created the load balancer.

Comment: I replaced zones from 'none' to zones = ['ap-southeast-1a','ap-southeast-1b']

still its showing the same result with boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request

Comment: Have you checkout the boto tutorial here (http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/elb_tut.html)?  Also, as the API docs (http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/elb.html#boto.ec2.elb.ELBConnection.create_load_balancer) show, the order of the parameters is different than what you are providing.  You have ``subnets`` and ``ports`` swapped.  Try using keyword parameters so the mapping is explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced zones from 'none' to 
        zones = ['ap-southeast-1a','ap-southeast-1b']

still its showing the same result with 
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

I've used below lines to create the loadbalancer,

`conn = boto.connect_elb()
lb = conn.create_load_balancer(name="lbName", listeners= [(80,80,'http')], zones=None, subnets=["subnet-xxxxxx", "subnet-xxxxxxx", "subnet-xxxxxxx"],security_groups=["sg-xxxxxxx"])`

Selecting two Subnets in different Availability Zones to provide me higher availability for load balancer.

Please ignore this link(for some testing purpose): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545dfd058/how-tfdfo-create-elb-inside-vpc-using-boto#answer-32311648